# Use of Input and Button in HTML

Tags: html, button, input

I am creating a webpage that redirects users to a specific webpage.

Some part of the URL of the specific webpage is constant and the rest is a variable.

If the webpage is `www.gotop.com/page1`. `www.gotop.com/`  is constant every time but the `page1` part changes. And I want to take the `page1` part as an input in my webpage and then a button to go to `www.gotop.com/page1`

I tried a lot but failed. My final code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<label for="name">Name (4 to 8 characters):</label>

<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">

   <body>
      <h1>The button Element</h1>

      <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='http://152.158.53.1:2222/q/"name"/';">Click Me!</button>

      <p>PLEASE WAIT...Redirecting to REALME 1 URL</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here I took the value of the `variable` part of URL from the input and concatenated it at the end of the `constant` part of the URL.

`window.location.href` redirects you to the desired URL.

This should help,

```js
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const page = document.getElementById('val').value
    window.location.href = `/constant/url/${page}`
  })
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" id="val">

  <button id="button">Click me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Let me know if you need any other help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a better solution

```js
function loadPage(){
     location.href = document.querySelector("#page_name").value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="page_name"/>
<button onclick="loadPage()">Go</button>
```

When the button is clicked, the loadPage function would be called. There, The value of the input is obtained and the page is redirected to that url.